# Lucene LINQ queries only returning one language version of an item

Tags: multilingual, lucene

If an item has a version in multiple languages I want lucene to return results with the different language versions. If I specify in the query x.Language=="zh-CN" then I get results for that language. If I don't specify a language in the query I only get "en" language items.

Is it not possible to get lucene to return multiple language versions for the same item?

The gist of the query is:

```
var languagePredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
var currentLanguage = Sitecore.Context.Language != null ? Sitecore.Context.Language.Name : DefaultLanguageName;

languagePredicate = languagePredicate.And(x => x.Language == currentLanguage || x.Language == "en");
```

The rest of the query varies but doesn't contain any further language constraints.

I think the below is the search query being executed by Sitecore requested by Jason Bert.

10832 10:49:57 INFO  ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_web_index): +(_language:zh-cn _language:en) +(+(+(+(+(+(+_path:6231de254dbc4b3e80562d337422aacc +_template:fe11c5a4bf2640808b2e8defc53c782a) +SpanWildcardQuery(videochannels:*445106304c474f9aa474adfd428143de*)) +SpanWildcardQuery(relatedfixtures:*e09af397a63f425798f263ee06b97687*)) +excludefromavtv:0) +publicationdate:{00010101t000000000z TO *]) +publicationdate:[* TO 20170106t104957807z}) - Filter :

Comment: Do you have multiple language versions in your index? Have you verified this with Luke http://www.getopt.org/luke/?

Comment: Have you got any code to share?

Comment: Can you show us your LINQ?

Comment: @IanGraham I can see index entries for both en and zh-cn

Comment: Could you supply the query being generated by Sitecore please? You can find this in the logs: <Data folder>\logs\Search.log.<Date/Time>.txt. This is a good place to look at what query is being sent to Lucene.

Comment: @JasonBert I've added what I believe is the query being executed.

Comment: If you're familiar with using Luke (program for querying your Lucene index) I would suggest seeing what results turn up when you use just the first part of the query: **+(_language:zh-cn _language:en)**. Whenever I have a query which isn't returning results I expect but I know the record are there I start to test parts of the query. Perhaps it's not the language part which is causing the issue, there's lots of other bits to your query. It's possible the **en** language version isn't matching against another part of your query.

Comment: @JasonBert I took your advice and tested just the first part of the query (plus a _group clause to look at the item I'm testing with) and I'm getting two results back. One for each language. This is the query I used: **+(_language:zh-cn _language:en) +(_group:81e522d773384d4aabfdee8e0ed70ecc)**

Comment: If you only get one language back for the full query then it definitely suggests your language which isn't being return isn't matching against one of your criteria. I would start adding parts of your query, or interrogate the data stored on the record for the language not being returned.

Comment: @ChrisWyatt - did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @JasonBert I did, thank you. The issue turned out to not actually be lucene but some unfinished code that was incorrectly filtering out some of the results.